# SPARQL: one query works; a similar query fails

Tags: sparql

Have two SPARQL queries that use the W3C pyRdfa extractor.

1: This query produces the expected results:

```
    PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?Content ?Author
FROM <http://www.w3.org/2007/08/pyRdfa/extract?uri=http://www.3kbo.com/examples/rdfa/simple.html>
WHERE {
    ?s dc:creator ?o .
    ?s dc:title ?Content .
    ?o foaf:name ?Author .
    }
ORDER BY ?Content
```

Here is the result:

```
http://www.sparql.org/sparql?query=PREFIX+dc%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+foaf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT+%3FContent+%3FAuthor%0D%0AFROM+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2007%2F08%2FpyRdfa%2Fextract%3Furi%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.3kbo.com%2Fexamples%2Frdfa%2Fsimple.html%3E%0D%0AWHERE+{%0D%0A%09%3Fs+dc%3Acreator+%3Fo+.%0D%0A%09%3Fs+dc%3Atitle+%3FContent+.%0D%0A%09%3Fo+foaf%3Aname+%3FAuthor+.%0D%0A%09}%0D%0AORDER+BY+%3FContent&default-graph-uri=&output=text&stylesheet=%2Fxml-to-html.xsl
```

2: This query does not produce a result similar to above:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?Content ?Author
FROM <http://www.w3.org/2007/08/pyRdfa/extract?uri=http://www.w3.org/2013/Talks/0902-Lisbon-IH/>
WHERE {
    ?s dc:author ?o .
    ?s dc:title ?Content .
    ?o foaf:name ?Author .
    }
ORDER BY ?Content
```

Here is the result:

```
http://www.sparql.org/sparql?query=PREFIX+dc%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX+foaf%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT+%3FContent+%3FAuthor%0D%0AFROM+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2007%2F08%2FpyRdfa%2Fextract%3Furi%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2013%2FTalks%2F0902-Lisbon-IH%2F%3E%0D%0AWHERE+{%0D%0A%09%3Fs+dc%3Aauthor+%3Fo+.%0D%0A%09%3Fs+dc%3Atitle+%3FContent+.%0D%0A%09%3Fo+foaf%3Aname+%3FAuthor+.%0D%0A%09}%0D%0AORDER+BY+%3FContent%0D%0A&default-graph-uri=&output=text&stylesheet=%2Fxml-to-html.xsl
```

Why does #2 fail to produce a result like #1?

Is there an error in the SPARQL code for #2?

Or is there a semantic difference in the structure of the RDFa associated with #1 and #2?

Am using this pyRdfa version in the examples:

```
http://www.w3.org/2007/08/pyRdfa/extract?uri=
```

Not using this version that occasionally confuses SPARQL processors:

```
http://www.w3.org/2012/pyRdfa/extract?uri=
```

TY for guidance here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`http://www.w3.org/2013/Talks/0902-Lisbon-IH/` uses RDFa 1.1, however `http://www.w3.org/2007/08/pyRdfa/extract?uri=` supports RDFa 1.0.

What you are using results in:

```
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
  xmlns:xhv="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#"
  xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="talk:">
     <xhv:icon rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/sw/favicon-sw.png"/>
     <xhv:stylesheet rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2006/02/charter-style.css"/>
     <xhv:stylesheet rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/Guide/pubrules-style.css"/>
     <xhv:copyright rdf:resource="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/3.0/"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

i.e. no triples of interest. This is because the source declares prefixes using RDFa 1.1 `@prefix` attribute, which doesn't exist in RDFa 1.0. Thus most abbreviated URLs are broken according to the older parser.

With the [newer parser](http://www.w3.org/2012/pyRdfa/extract?uri=http://www.w3.org/2013/Talks/0902-Lisbon-IH/') you find many more triples, including:

```
...
talk: a ore:ResourceMap;
dc:author <http://www.ivan-herman.net/foaf#me>;
dc:date "$Date: 2013-08-27 07:51:24 $";
dc:title "Introduction to Linked Open Data";
ore:describes <http://www.w3.org/2012/0902-Lisbon-IH/#talk> .
...
```

Which is what you are looking for.

*However*

As a final fly in the ointment the two documents are using different versions of the dublin core namespace. RDFa 1.1 binds the `dc` prefix to the updated `http://purl.org/dc/terms/` by default, which throws off your query.

So try:

```
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> # FIXED dc
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?Content ?Author
 # Use RDFa 1.1 parser
FROM <http://www.w3.org/2012/pyRdfa/extract?uri=http://www.w3.org/2013/Talks/0902-Lisbon-IH/>
WHERE {
    ?s dc:author ?o .
    ?s dc:title ?Content .
    ?o foaf:name ?Author .
}
ORDER BY ?Content
```

[Tada](http://sparql.org/sparql?query=PREFIX%20dc%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%20%23%20FIXED%20dc%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT%20%3FContent%20%3FAuthor%0D%0AFROM%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2012%2FpyRdfa%2Fextract%3Furi%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2013%2FTalks%2F0902-Lisbon-IH%2F%3E%20%23%20Use%20RDFa%201.1%20parser%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20dc%3Aauthor%20%3Fo%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fs%20dc%3Atitle%20%3FContent%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fo%20foaf%3Aname%20%3FAuthor%20.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FContent&default-graph-uri=&output=text&stylesheet=%2Fxml-to-html.xsl), results.

Comment: OK! TY. So, for #2, I updated the query to use "FROM <http://www.w3.org/2012/pyRdfa/extract?uri=http://www.w3.org/2013/Talks/0902-Lisbon-IH/>"  Still, no result. If I run the extractor stand alone, I see 6 triples, 4 of which meet the SPARQL variables. Do you see a problem with the SPARQL query?

Comment: Did you notice my edit mentioning the dc prefix issue? I've provided a full working query.